# Get data from XML using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

i have this **xml file** :

```
<cv xmlns="http://hr.joinvision.com/xml/3_0">
  <personalInformation>
    <firstname>Bernard</firstname>
    <lastname>Henry</lastname>
    <gender>
      <code>m</code>
      <name>Monsieur</name>
    </gender>
    <title>Exec. MBA</title>
    <isced>
      <code>5A</code>
      <name>Ma�trise universitaire ou �quivalent</name>
    </isced>
    <address/>
    <email>negociationbhfc@gmail.com</email>
    <phoneNumber>0617135919</phoneNumber>
  </personalInformation>
  <work>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1981-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateTo>1984-01-01+01:00</dateTo>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1981</dateFromFuzzy>
      <dateToFuzzy>1984</dateToFuzzy>
      <duration>36</duration>
      <current>false</current>
      <operationArea>
        <code>ass</code>
        <name>Assistance</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>pm</code>
        <name>Direction de Projet</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>secr</code>
        <name>Bureau du Secr�taire</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>offi</code>
        <name>Gestion du Bureau</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>sale</code>
        <name>Ventes en G�n�ral</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>retai</code>
        <name>Vente au D�tail</name>
        <weight>0.7</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <topic>"TV-Vid�o"</topic>
      <comments>Adjoint chef r�gional des ventes "TV-Vid�o"(CA de 60 M�)
1980-81
Attach� commercial (CA de 6 M�)</comments>
      <plainText>* Soci�t� PHILIPS
1981-84
Adjoint chef r�gional des ventes "TV-Vid�o"(CA de 60 M�)
1980-81
Attach� commercial (CA de 6 M�)</plainText>
      <company>PHILIPS</company>
      <function>Adjoint chef</function>
      <position>
        <code>mgmtl</code>
        <name>Chef d'�quipe</name>
      </position>
      <project>false</project>
    </phase>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1978-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateTo>2021-12-01+01:00</dateTo>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1978</dateFromFuzzy>
      <dateToFuzzy>2021-12</dateToFuzzy>
      <duration>516</duration>
      <current>true</current>
      <location>
        <postcode>40210</postcode>
        <city>D�sseldorf</city>
        <country>
          <code>DE</code>
          <name>Allemagne</name>
        </country>
        <state>Nordrhein-Westfalen</state>
      </location>
      <operationArea>
        <code>mark</code>
        <name>Marketing</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <industry>
        <code>72</code>
        <name>Recherche d�veloppement scientifique</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </industry>
      <comments>79
Charg� de d�velopper, en Allemagne, des activit�s publi-promotionnelles en faveur de vins et alcools fran�ais</comments>
      <plainText>* SOPEXA Deutschland - D�sseldorf
1978-79
Charg� de d�velopper, en Allemagne, des activit�s publi-promotionnelles en faveur de vins et alcools fran�ais</plainText>
      <company>SOPEXA Deutschland</company>
      <position>
        <code>ma</code>
        <name>Employ�</name>
      </position>
      <project>false</project>
    </phase>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1976-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateTo>1978-01-01+01:00</dateTo>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1976</dateFromFuzzy>
      <dateToFuzzy>1978</dateToFuzzy>
      <duration>24</duration>
      <current>false</current>
      <location>
        <country>
          <code>FR</code>
          <name>France</name>
        </country>
      </location>
      <location>
        <city>New York</city>
        <country>
          <code>US</code>
          <name>�tats-Unis</name>
        </country>
      </location>
      <operationArea>
        <code>retai</code>
        <name>Vente au D�tail</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>adve</code>
        <name>Publicit�</name>
        <weight>0.7</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>mark</code>
        <name>Marketing</name>
        <weight>0.7</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>ware</code>
        <name>Entreposage / Logistique des Marchandises</name>
        <weight>0.7</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <comments>* FOOD AND WINES FROM FRANCE Inc. (SOPEXA USA) - New York
Responsable local de la mise en place de campagnes publi-promotionnelles (pour vins et fromages fran�ais) aupr�s de la distribution sur plusieurs r�gions des USA</comments>
      <plainText>* FOOD AND WINES FROM FRANCE Inc. (SOPEXA USA) - New York
1976-78
Responsable local de la mise en place de campagnes publi-promotionnelles (pour vins et fromages fran�ais) aupr�s de la distribution sur plusieurs r�gions des USA</plainText>
      <company>FRANCE Inc.</company>
      <function>Responsable</function>
      <position>
        <code>ma</code>
        <name>Employ�</name>
      </position>
      <project>false</project>
    </phase>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>2020-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateFromFuzzy>2020-01</dateFromFuzzy>
      <subphase>false</subphase>
      <current>false</current>
      <comments>negociation-bhfc.f r - negociationbhfc@gmail.com - 0617135919</comments>
      <plainText>Janvier 2020 - negociation-bhfc.f r - negociationbhfc@gmail.com - 0617135919</plainText>
      <company>negociation-bhfc.f r</company>
      <position>
        <code>ma</code>
        <name>Employ�</name>
      </position>
      <project>false</project>
    </phase>
  </work>
  <education>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1984-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1984</dateFromFuzzy>
      <duration>12</duration>
      <current>false</current>
      <comments>Sciences de l'Education</comments>
      <plainText>1984 Sciences de l'Education</plainText>
      <completed>true</completed>
    </phase>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1976-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1976</dateFromFuzzy>
      <duration>12</duration>
      <current>false</current>
      <operationArea>
        <code>elec</code>
        <name>Ing�nierie �lectrique/�lectronique</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <comments>Dipl�me H.E.C.
Langues: Anglais courant - Allemand</comments>
      <plainText>1976 Dipl�me H.E.C. Langues: Anglais courant - Allemand</plainText>
      <isced>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>Enseignement secondaire (premier cycle)</name>
      </isced>
      <educationType>
        <code>ed68</code>
        <name>Dipl�me</name>
      </educationType>
      <completed>true</completed>
    </phase>
    <phase>
      <dateFrom>1984-01-01+01:00</dateFrom>
      <dateTo>2020-01-01+01:00</dateTo>
      <dateFromFuzzy>1984</dateFromFuzzy>
      <dateToFuzzy>2020</dateToFuzzy>
      <duration>432</duration>
      <current>false</current>
      <location>
        <postcode>75001</postcode>
        <city>PARIS, HEC, PONTS Paris</city>
        <country>
          <code>FR</code>
          <name>France</name>
        </country>
        <state>�le-de-France</state>
      </location>
      <skill>
        <code>masch</code>
        <name>Construction de Machines</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </skill>
      <skill>
        <code>o</code>
        <name>Oracle</name>
        <weight>0.9</weight>
      </skill>
      <skill>
        <code>lawye</code>
        <name>Avocat</name>
        <weight>0.8</weight>
      </skill>
      <operationArea>
        <code>sale</code>
        <name>Ventes en G�n�ral</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>cc</code>
        <name>Helpdesk/Support Technique</name>
        <weight>0.7</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>retai</code>
        <name>Vente au D�tail</name>
        <weight>0.5</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>advoc</code>
        <name>Carri�re Judiciaire</name>
        <weight>0.4</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>pm</code>
        <name>Direction de Projet</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <operationArea>
        <code>cust</code>
        <name>Service � la Client�le</name>
        <weight>1.0</weight>
      </operationArea>
      <topic>" Responsable des achats "</topic>
      <comments>Interventions en:
N�gociation raisonn�e/r�solution de conflit . N�gociation commerciale
Formation de formateurs/ing�nierie p�dagogique . Management
* Exemples de mission:
Formation � la n�gociation et la r�solution de conflits (en fran�ais ou en anglais) :
* de managers, ing�nieurs, chefs de projet (CNES, ONERA, INGEROP, RAZEL, DGAC)
* de vendeurs (ORACLE, VEOLIA, CASINO, BNPP)
* d'acheteurs (SG, SANOFI, LAFARGE Ciment, CASINO, C-DISCOUNT)
* d'avocats (FIDAL 2017-2018 et ETELIO 2019)
* d'�tudiants (CENTRALE PARIS, HEC, PONTS Paris Tech, MINES Paris Tech, �cole)
POLYTECHNIQUE, Corps des MINES, Corps des PONTS
Interventions
dans des projets de formation de dimension internationale et interculturelle (en fran�ais ou anglais) pour acheteurs (LAFARGE, TOTAL) ou managers (SAINT GOBAIN)
Executive MBA HEC : workshop sur la n�gociation raisonn�e (2018)
MBA sp�cialis� " Responsable des achats " de l'Institut LEONARD DE VINCI (class� 7�me)
MBA-Achats de France en 2016): formation de ces futurs acheteurs � la n�gociation raisonn�e
Interventions � l'�tranger : au Canada pour LAFARGE (acheteurs - 2001), au Gabon pour
VEOLIA (acheteurs - 2010) et au Maroc pour JESA/OCP (acheteurs - 2017-20) et SAHAM (2018)</comments>
      <plainText>1984-2020
 * Interventions en:
. N�gociation raisonn�e/r�solution de conflit . N�gociation commerciale
. Formation de formateurs/ing�nierie p�dagogique . Management
 * Exemples de mission:
Formation � la n�gociation et la r�solution de conflits (en fran�ais ou en anglais) :
* de managers, ing�nieurs, chefs de projet (CNES, ONERA, INGEROP, RAZEL, DGAC)
* de vendeurs (ORACLE, VEOLIA, CASINO, BNPP)
* d'acheteurs (SG, SANOFI, LAFARGE Ciment, CASINO, C-DISCOUNT)
* d'avocats (FIDAL 2017-2018 et ETELIO 2019)
* d'�tudiants (CENTRALE PARIS, HEC, PONTS Paris Tech, MINES Paris Tech, �cole
POLYTECHNIQUE, Corps des MINES, Corps des PONTS)
Interventions
dans des projets de formation de dimension internationale et interculturelle (en fran�ais ou anglais) pour acheteurs (LAFARGE, TOTAL) ou managers (SAINT GOBAIN)
Executive MBA HEC : workshop sur la n�gociation raisonn�e (2018)
MBA sp�cialis� " Responsable des achats " de l'Institut LEONARD DE VINCI (class� 7�me
MBA-Achats de France en 2016): formation de ces futurs acheteurs � la n�gociation raisonn�e
Interventions � l'�tranger : au Canada pour LAFARGE (acheteurs - 2001), au Gabon pour
VEOLIA (acheteurs - 2010) et au Maroc pour JESA/OCP (acheteurs - 2017-20) et SAHAM (2018)
Bernard HENRY Formation Conseil</plainText>
      <isced>
        <code>3</code>
        <name>Enseignement secondaire (deuxi�me cycle)</name>
      </isced>
      <educationType>
        <code>ed55</code>
        <name>�cole secondaire compr�hensive</name>
      </educationType>
      <schoolname>�cole POLYTECHNIQUE</schoolname>
      <graduation>Executive MBA</graduation>
      <graduation>Executive MBA HEC</graduation>
      <graduation>MBA</graduation>
      <completed>true</completed>
    </phase>
  </education>
  <publications/>
  <additionalInformation>
    <language>
      <code>DE</code>
      <name>Allemand</name>
      <level>
        <code>C1</code>
        <name>Courant</name>
      </level>
    </language>
    <language>
      <code>FR</code>
      <name>Fran�ais</name>
    </language>
    <language>
      <code>EN</code>
      <name>Anglais</name>
    </language>
    <interests>DE CONSULTANT-FORMATEUR - 1984-2020
 * Interventions en:
. N�gociation raisonn�e/r�solution de conflit . N�gociation commerciale
. Formation de formateurs/ing�nierie p�dagogique . Management
 * Exemples de mission:
Formation � la n�gociation et la r�solution de conflits (en fran�ais ou en anglais) :
* de managers, ing�nieurs, chefs de projet (CNES, ONERA, INGEROP, RAZEL, DGAC)
* de vendeurs (ORACLE, VEOLIA, CASINO, BNPP)
* d'acheteurs (SG, SANOFI, LAFARGE Ciment, CASINO, C-DISCOUNT)
* d'avocats (FIDAL 2017-2018 et ETELIO 2019)
* d'�tudiants (CENTRALE PARIS, HEC, PONTS Paris Tech, MINES Paris Tech, �cole
POLYTECHNIQUE, Corps des MINES, Corps des PONTS)
Interventions
dans des projets de formation de dimension internationale et interculturelle (en fran�ais ou anglais) pour acheteurs (LAFARGE, TOTAL) ou managers (SAINT GOBAIN)
Executive MBA HEC : workshop sur la n�gociation raisonn�e (2018)
MBA sp�cialis� " Responsable des achats " de l'Institut LEONARD DE VINCI (class� 7�me
MBA-Achats de France en 2016): formation de ces futurs acheteurs � la n�gociation raisonn�e
Interventions � l'�tranger : au Canada pour LAFARGE (acheteurs - 2001), au Gabon pour
VEOLIA (acheteurs - 2010) et au Maroc pour JESA/OCP (acheteurs - 2017-20) et SAHAM (2018)
Bernard HENRY Formation Conseil
Janvier 2020 - negociation-bhfc.f r - negociationbhfc@gmail.com - 0617135919</interests>
  </additionalInformation>
  <objectives/>
  <statistics>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>72</code>
      <name>Recherche d�veloppement scientifique</name>
      <weight>100.0</weight>
      <duration>528</duration>
      <domain>NACE</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>o</code>
      <name>Oracle</name>
      <weight>67.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>Skill</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>lawye</code>
      <name>Avocat</name>
      <weight>59.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>Skill</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>masch</code>
      <name>Construction de Machines</name>
      <weight>74.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>Skill</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>ma</code>
      <name>Employ�</name>
      <weight>100.0</weight>
      <duration>552</duration>
      <domain>Position</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>cc</code>
      <name>Helpdesk/Support Technique</name>
      <weight>26.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>mark</code>
      <name>Marketing</name>
      <weight>100.0</weight>
      <duration>552</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>cust</code>
      <name>Service � la Client�le</name>
      <weight>37.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>advoc</code>
      <name>Carri�re Judiciaire</name>
      <weight>15.0</weight>
      <duration>433</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>pm</code>
      <name>Direction de Projet</name>
      <weight>37.0</weight>
      <duration>469</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>retai</code>
      <name>Vente au D�tail</name>
      <weight>19.0</weight>
      <duration>494</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>sale</code>
      <name>Ventes en G�n�ral</name>
      <weight>37.0</weight>
      <duration>469</duration>
      <domain>OperationArea</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>DE</code>
      <name>Allemagne</name>
      <weight>100.0</weight>
      <duration>528</duration>
      <domain>ISOCountry</domain>
    </codeSummary>
    <codeSummary>
      <code>FR</code>
      <name>France</name>
      <weight>74.0</weight>
      <duration>458</duration>
      <domain>ISOCountry</domain>
    </codeSummary>
  </statistics>
</cv>
```

i want to get the data from it so im using :

```
def personal_infos(xml):
    tree = et.fromstring(xml)
    namespace = tree.xpath('namespace-uri(.)')
    firstname = tree.find(".//{%s}firstname" % namespace).text
    lastname = tree.find(".//{%s}lastname"% namespace).text
    email = tree.find(".//{%s}email"% namespace).text
    gender = tree.find(".//{%s}code"% namespace).text
    phone = tree.find(".//{%s}phoneNumber"% namespace).text
    personal_infos = ({"first_name":firstname,"last_name":lastname,"gender":gender,"email":email,"phone_number":phone})
    print(personal_infos)
```

i'm wondering how to create a loop to get all because in `<work>` i have so many `<phases>` i can't use the same code

**example of what i need :**

> i need to extract all the  infos (datefrom , dateto ,current, operation area... ) from work

I tried this :

```
def work_infos(xml):
    f = io.StringIO(xml)
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elem in root.iter():
        for p in tree.findall('.//work//phase'):
            df = tree.find('.//dateFrom')
            dateTo = tree.find('.//dateTo')
```

it returns `nothing`

i'm new in python any kind of guide will be helpful ,thanks

Comment: You have non-unique child tags in `phase` so you cannot store that data in a dictionary because the keys need to be unique. How would you like the data?

Comment: can i store it in a dataframe ??

Comment: note that `//` is the `Recursive Descent Operator`, `//work` means find a `<work>` element **anywhere, it ignores hierarchy**. [XPath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) -- that means `.//work` isn't getting children in the tree you're descending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `ETree` can also do this task but I am more familiar with `BeautifulSoup`. Anyways, both of them have similar approaches to handle the XML data.

In case using `BeautifulSoup`, first, use `find_all('phase')` to get the list of all phases inside work. Then, iterate through the list and retrieve the value one by one. Use `.text.strip()` to get text node and make sure that there is no space at first and last position. Create them as a dict and append to the list one by one. Last, convert the list of dict as dataframe using `pd.DataFrame`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_tag(tag_name):
    try:
        return phase.find(tag_name).text.strip()
    except:
        return None

xml_doc = BeautifulSoup('<your_xml>','lxml')
phases = xml_doc.find_all('phase')
phase_list = list()
for phase in phases:
    phase_dict = dict()
    phase_dict['datefrom'] = find_tag('datefrom')
    phase_dict['dateto'] = find_tag('dateto')
    phase_dict['datefromfuzzy'] = find_tag('datefromfuzzy')
    phase_dict['datetofuzzy'] = find_tag('datetofuzzy')
    phase_dict['duration'] = find_tag('duration')
    
    # continue to extract next value node here
    # ...

    phase_list.append(phase_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(phase_list)
print(df)
```

Output:

> ```
>            datefrom            dateto datefromfuzzy datetofuzzy duration
> 0  1981-01-01+01:00  1984-01-01+01:00          1981        1984       36
> 1  1978-01-01+01:00  2021-12-01+01:00          1978     2021-12      516
> 2  1976-01-01+01:00  1978-01-01+01:00          1976        1978       24
> 3  2020-01-01+01:00              None       2020-01        None     None
> 4  1984-01-01+01:00              None          1984        None       12
> 5  1976-01-01+01:00              None          1976        None       12
> 6  1984-01-01+01:00  2020-01-01+01:00          1984        2020      432
> ```